# set header on get request android

Tags: android, http-headers

I try to set a http autentification with android

this is my class

http://pastebin.com/SB9TKtQZ

I use like this

```
EditText user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.referent_login_input);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.referent_password_input);

Api login = new Api(getString(R.string.api_url));
login.updateUrl("login");
login.updateHeader(user.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
String connect = login.get();
```

My php is

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ) {
    echo "no !!!";
}
else {
    echo "yes";
}
```

and I always have no !!!

I set something in my EditText

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure you could try this on regular browser to see whether your PHP installation allows basic authentication. Head your browser to ``http://username:password@yourserver.com`` and see what comes. I think this triggers a basic authorisation request.

Comment: Thanks, it was due to my server